# Wireless mouse lag windows 10

Tags: windows-10, lag, wireless-mouse

so after I reinstalled my windows I am experiencing random mouse lag spikes. The closest thing I found to a pattern is when starting a program/game the heavier the bigger chance of lag. However that is not a 100% guarantee it will lag. I have tried to solve this for couple of weeks and I am out of ideas.. Maybe someone else will have more ideas.

Mouse is: Microsoft wireless mouse 3500

Things I have tried:

- Change batteries
- Cleaned mouse laser whole
- Change wireless receiver to different usb ports
- Change mousepad. Even tried white peace of paper.
- Change mouse (with another wireless I got same problem but with my old wired one the lag was gone)
- In device manager disable power saving mode of usb ports
- In device manager update mouse drivers
- Download latest mouse drivers
- Downloaded latest Nvidia drivers
- Installed various drivers for motherboard and cpu
- Disabled cortana
- Deleted realtec audio drivers
- Deleted malwarebites (I dont have avira or avast as this was another fix I saw on the web)
- Checked taskmanager for any cpu,ram or gpu performance spikes when the lag occurs but everything stayed on low during the lag episodes.
- In mouse settings disabled scroll inactive windows , enhance pointer precision , changed mouse scheme to none.
- Changed in nvidia control panel monitor refresh rates to different levels.
- Mouse distance from receiver doesnt seem to make much effect since the mouse is half a meter from the computer.
- in power management - advanced settings changing all sleep options for usb/harddrive to never

Things I suspect:

- SSD
- Videocard
- Windows Updates (since before the reinstalation I had them disabled but now they are turned on)

Comment: Have you checked Event Viewer for any reports that coincide with the lag spikes?

Comment: Try adding USB ports closer to the mouse and add the wireless receiver there. The receiver may be too far.

Comment: @music2myear just checked but couldn't see any errors or warnings for the exact times.

Comment: to my experience all wireless mice are lagging - some more some less so first of all don't worry so much. To check if it is mouse problem, I would first check the mouse (and receiver) on other PCs.

Comment: @mikhailV its just annoying because it is a good mouse and I have been using the same model for years without any problems. But after reinstalling with latest windows updates this started happening so I strongly suspect it is a software issue.

Comment: I see it sucks. So as said, I would try this mouse on several other PCs, ideally also on some other OS e.g. LInux and compare how it works there. Changing location might worth trying, as it can interfere with other wireless devices. So at least to know if it is mouse issue or not.

Comment: It IS a good idea to try the mouse on a different computer. That will help rule out (or prove) the problem exists with the mouse itself.